# Why am I not able to use URL, HttpUrlConnection in jenkins shared library?

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a simple shared library that allows execute http GET. 
These files are stored in vars dir:
simpleHttpGet.groovy

```
String call(String rawUrl){
    new URL(rawUrl).text
}
```

httpGet.groovy

```
String call(String rawUrl){
    URL url = new URL(rawUrl)
    HttpURLConnection connection = url.openConnection()
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET")
    connection.setConnectTimeout(1000)
    connection.setDoInput(true)
    def text = null
    try {
        echo 'trying to connect'
        connection.connect()
        echo 'connected'
        def stream = connection.getInputStream()
        echo "stream $stream"
        text = stream.text
    } finally {
        echo 'disconnected'
        connection.disconnect()
    }
    echo text
    return text
}
```

When I use simpleHttpGet.groovy and httpGet.groovy in pipeline the first one returns null and the second one has null InputStream. Why does not it work?
There is a full pipeline and execution result.

```
@Library('simple-http-get') _
pipeline {
    agent any

    options {
        timestamps()
    }

    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo 'curl'
                    def curlResponse = sh(script: 'curl -X GET https://google.com', returnStdout: true)
                    echo curlResponse
                    echo 'simpleHttpGet'
                    def simpleResponse = simpleHttpGet('https://google.com')
                    echo simpleResponse
                    echo 'httpGet'
                    def httpGetResponse = httpGet("https://google.com")
                    echo httpGetResponse
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] timestamps
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
curl
[Pipeline] sh
+ curl -X GET https://google.com
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   220  100   220    0     0    820      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   820
100   220  100   220    0     0    820      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   817
[Pipeline] echo
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>

[Pipeline] echo
simpleHttpGet
[Pipeline] echo
null
[Pipeline] echo
httpGet
[Pipeline] echo
trying to connect
[Pipeline] echo
connected
[Pipeline] echo
stream null
[Pipeline] echo
disconnected
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timestamps
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'text' on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.getProperty(NullObject.java:60)
...
```

Comment: Try to print connection.getResponseCode() and connection.getResponseMessage(). Also note that by default http connection in Java follows redirects. You could turn it off by calling setFollowRedirects(false)

Comment: @daggett everything returns null but when I use raw java.net.Socket I get the same response as in curl command. I've printed connection.getPermission and it looks ok... (permission ("java.net.SocketPermission" "google.com:80" "connect,resolve"))

Comment: strange... the last idea - have you tried to set @NonCPS on function?

Comment: @Lukasz did you ever find an answer to this. I have the same issue, but in my case, it works from a jenkins running on my local laptop, but not on a corporate jenkins server- curl works in both places